# Como obtener el tiempo de demora de una respuesta

Tags: php

Quería saber como se puede hacer para obtener el tiempo de demora de una respuesta hacia un servidor externo. Tengo un tracert, pero devuelve muchas lineas y sólo necesito saber los MS del tracert.

Comment: una respuesta de que? una consulta a la BD o de que?

Comment: Prácticamente la totalidad de los navegadores disponen de una herramienta de depuración. En Chrome se abre pulsando Control + Mayúsculas + J )pestaña "Network"), en Firefox Control + Mayúsculas + K, en Edge y Explorer es F12, etc... Aparecen detalles del tiempo de conexión, envío y recepción de cabeceras, comienzo de la recepción de datos, etc. También dispones de la herramienta [`ab`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/ab) para medir el rendimiento de un servidor web. Si no es eso, todos agradeceríamos que explicaras mejor qué quieres conseguir con algún ejemplo.

Comment: @element  Lo que yo quisiera hacer es hacer un comando con php a una ip para que me de la respuesta, básicamente lo que en cmd sería (tracert x.x.x.x) y necesito que php me devuelva el tiempo de demora, no es algo de client side digamos

Comment: @OscarGarcia Eso

Comment: ¿El tiempo que se demora en acceder el script PHP a una página externa o el tiempo que tardó el usuario en cargar el PHP en curso? Si es lo último, no es posible ya que los tiempos de establecimiento de conexión al servidor, etc no son conocidos por el script PHP, su ejecución comienza pasado un tiempo desde el comienzo del establecimiento de la conexión (tras el procesamiento del servidor web). Edito: Leyendo varias veces tu comentario parece que quieres ejecutar un `ping` o `tracert` desde PHP. ¿Podrías confirmarlo editando tu pregunta y agregando tu sistema operativo a ella?

Comment: @OscarGarcia Disculpa la demora, si, un tracert, porque la ip a la que quiero consultar, no recibe pings, así lo decidieron, sólo puedo hacer tracert, pero no quiero recibir toda la ruta, sino el MS más exacto

Comment: Tu respuesta fue cerrada porque no estaba claro lo que preguntabas. Para que se reabra debes editarla y poner en ella que quieres hacer algo lo más parecido a un `tracert` en PHP. Te recomiendo poner el sistema operativo en el que corre el servidor ya que es determinante para la solución.

Answer (score 1):

En Firefox si presiona f12 hay una lista de herramientas ahí en RED cuando hace un petición Get o Post te dice el tiempo en ms

Comment: Favor de no responder a preguntas tan mal planteadas

Comment: @element Está bien por su parte aportar

Comment: Esteban, @element tiene toda la razón en sus dos comentarios. En el primero solicitándote más información acerca de lo que deseas obtener y en este aconsejando no responder a preguntas hasta no conocer más datos (como hice yo, que escribí un comentario y no una respuesta).